# How can i use batchRunReports method in php?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I just want understand how i can run batchRunReports in php, I tried an example but it gives a complex Fatal Error message. I looked at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/batchRunReports) but couldn't find anything related to my problem. I can run the query I want with the tool in the documentation, but I could not pass it to php.

```
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\MetricAggregation;

$property = "properties/XXXXXXXXX";

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
$client->batchRunReports([
    "requests" => [
        [   
            "property" => $property,
            "dataRanges" => [
                new DateRange(["start_date" => "7daysAgo"], ["end_date" => "today"]),
            ],
            "dimensions" => [
                new Dimension(["name" => "eventName"]),
            ],
            "metrics" => [
                new Metric(["name" => "eventCount"]),
            ]
        ],
        [
            "property" => $property,
            "dataRanges" => [
                new DateRange(["start_date" => "7daysAgo"], ["end_date" => "today"]),
            ],
            "dimensions" => [
                new Dimension(["name" => "deviceCategory"]),
            ],
            "metrics" => [
                new Metric(["name" => "activeUsers"]),
            ]
        ],
    ]
]);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportRequest. in F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil.php:198 Stack trace: 
> #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField.php(187): Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkMessage(Array, 'Google\Analytic...') 
> #1 F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil.php(210): Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField->offsetSet(NULL, Array) 
> #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\vendor\google\analytics-data\src\V1beta\BatchRunReportsRequest.php(126): Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkRepeatedField(Array, 11, 'Google\Analytic...') 
> #3 F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\vendor\google\analytics-data\src\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient.php(421): Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BatchRunReportsRequest->setRequests(Array) 
> #4 F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\test.php(46): Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient->batchRunReports(Array) 
> #5 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\other\2_template\api-test-completed\google-analytics\vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil.php on line 198

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the RunReportRequest objects inside the array in "requests" to run a batchRunReports. Don't forget to add the "property" as you did in your requests for the batchRunReports.

```php
$response = $client->batchRunReports([
    "property" => $property,
      "requests" => [
        new RunReportRequest(
        [   
            "property" => $property,
            "date_ranges" => [
                new DateRange(["start_date" => "7daysAgo", "end_date" => "today"]),
            ],
            "dimensions" => [
                new Dimension(["name" => "eventName"]),
            ],
            "metrics" => [
                new Metric(["name" => "eventCount"]),
            ]
        ]),
        new RunReportRequest([
            "property" => $property,
            "date_ranges" => [
                new DateRange(["start_date" => "7daysAgo", "end_date" => "today"]),
            ],
            "dimensions" => [
                new Dimension(["name" => "deviceCategory"]),
            ],
            "metrics" => [
                new Metric(["name" => "activeUsers"]),
            ]
        ]),
    ]
]);
```